# Checking success of http status

Tags: http-status-codes

In Classic ASP, I'm setting a page's status to 410 Gone, as the contents were previously removed by our administrators. Is there any way to check if this was successfully applied or not?

Comment: You mean verifying the server returns a 410 for a specific url? Are you talking about in code, or just a tool to verify that?

Comment: You should be able to use Fiddler to make a request for the content; if the server responds with HTTP Status Code 410 then you know it has been successfully applied. Fiddler is here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check this by many debugging tools or websites. Here's a couple of websites:

- http://web-sniffer.net/
- http://www.axandra.com/free-online-seo-tool/status-code.php

Answer (score 1):

As @dash pointed out [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a good tool for debugging and verifying HTML / server responses.